# Sitecore Publish Agent not picking up queued items,for incremental publishing

Tags: sitecore, publish

We have the Publish Agent set to run every 15 minutes with 'Incremental Publish'. Sitecore client users 'Check In' and 'Approve' an item in Sitecore to queue the item. They can also do a manual publish if required to make something live immediately. We are seeing some issues where some of the items that are checked in and approved through the workflow are not getting picked up by the scheduled publisher. Also, when the user tries to publish from the publish tab the parent publishes but not the child items. The child items have to be published one at a time.

To me the issue seems to be that these approved items are not getting added to the publishing queue. But I am not certain of this.

We installed a module called 'Publishing Status Manager' which basically shows a Sitecore user the various publish operations that are active or in queue. This problem started occurring after that module was installed. I am not sure if that is the cause of this issue though.

I am looking for some suggestions/advice on where to look and how to fix this issue.

Comment: It was just the module that we installed that over wrote the publishing pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items that are in the final workflow step is always added to the publish queue. I guess your issue revolves around the fact that the items in the workflow is not in the final workflow step. Please ensure that the actually reaches this state.

If you would like to check what's in the publish queue, read this article:

http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/sitecore-publish-queue/

You must use the code as described in "THE CURRENT VIEW" as it tells you what is published next time an incremental publish is executed.

Also, ensure that the publish agent publishes the current targets and correct languages:

```
  <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00">
    <param desc="source database">master</param>
    <param desc="target database">web</param>
    <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
    <param desc="languages">en, da</param>
  </agent>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just the module that we installed that over wrote the publishing pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Publish agent will not pick up queued item if value of publishing.checksecurity is true in web.config. You can make this value as false. Or else create a user, give it proper access rights and override the agent to switch the user.